# List parsing in Java/Groovy

Tags: java, list, parsing, jenkins, groovy

I like to parse the following list.

```
LUT = [
    [branch: "test", name: 'a', image_name: 'abc'],
    [branch: "test", name: 'b', image_name: 'abc'],
    [branch: "test", name: 'c', image_name: 'abc'],
    [branch: "test-1", name: 'd', image_name: 'abc'],
    [branch: "test-1", name: 'e', image_name: 'abc'],
    [branch: "test-2", name: 'f', image_name: 'abc'],
    [branch: "test-2", name: 'g', image_name: 'abc'],
    [branch: "test-2", name: 'h', image_name: 'abc'],
    [branch: "test-3", name: 'i', image_name: 'abc'],
    [branch: "test-3", name: 'j', image_name: 'abc'],
    [branch: "test-4", name: 'k', image_name: 'abc'],
    [branch: "test-5", name: 'l', image_name: 'abc'],
]
```

For now what i do is :

```
result = [:]

    for (map in LUT)
    {
        if (!result.containsKey(map['branch']))
        {
            println map['name'] // prints the unique name
            result.put(map['branch'], map['name'])
        }
    }
```

This will result in a 1 to 1 map in a list:

```
[test:a, test-1:d, test-2:f, test-3:i, test-4:k, test-5:l]
```

But what i want to have is a list of lists like:

```
[test:[a:abc], test-1:[d:abc], test-2:[f:abc], test-3:[i:abc], test-4:[k:abc], test-5:[l:abc]]
```

Can any one assist me on this , Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know groovy but I think I can help.

instead of this:

```
result = [:]

for (map in LUT)
{
    if (!result.containsKey(map['branch']))
    {
        println map['name'] // prints the unique name
        result.put(map['branch'], map['name'])
    }
}
```

You need something like this:

```
result = [:]

for (map in LUT)
{
    if (!result.containsKey(map['branch']))
    {
        println map['name'] // prints the unique name
        newMap = [:]
        newMap.put(map['name'], map['image_name'])
        result.put(map['branch'], newMap)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help , i am learning .

Comment: Do you know how i can retrieve and branch and edit its image_name in the list?

Comment: check out this: https://www.baeldung.com/groovy-maps